# IF statement in cmd, how to use the current time to show an error

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I am writing a code in a batch file for a school system, the code shows when did the student changed his/her password.
I had a problem with the the system, it shows that all the student username have changed there password but some users show the current time and date. 
I am trying to make an if statement saying: if the date and time of the user == the date and time of the current day. show an echo message.

I have tried alot of codes to work it doesn't seem that they were right.

here is one of the codes:

```
(for /f "delims=" %%i in ('net user %MyName% /domain ^| find /I "password last set"') do set MyResult=User 
%MyName%: %%i)

if "%DATE%-%TIME%" EQU "%MyResult%" echo "password not changed."
```

it would also be really useful if this code would be in vbs that would be perfect.

thank you in advance. :)

Comment: you get %MyName% in the `for`, but check %MyResult% in the `if`. Typo?

Comment: Output of `net user` is `18.03.2014 19:59:36` (space between Date and Time) (at least on my computer). You check `%DATE%-%TIME%` (dash between Date and Time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a VBScript for you. Since the time may change slightly by the time `net user` returns and you have the opportunity to test it, this script checks to see if it's within 10 seconds of the current date and time. Feel free to adjust the threshold as you see fit.

```
' Create the command string...
strCommand = "cmd /c net user " & strUser & " /domain | find ""Password last set"""

' Run the command and capture its output...
strOut = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec(strCommand).StdOut.ReadAll

' Remove the label ("Password last set") leaving only the date and time...
strOut = Trim(Mid(strOut, Len("Password last set") + 1))

If IsDate(strOut) Then
    If Abs(DateDiff("s", strOut, Date)) < 10 Then

        ' Password set within last 10 seconds

    End If
End If
```